# Derivation of Chebyshev's Inequality in Harold Larson's book

Tags: mathematical-statistics

In section 5.5 page 277 of Harold Larson's Introduction to Probability Theory and Statistical Inference 3rd edition he develops Chebyshev's inequality as follows:

> Assume $X$ is a random variable and $\epsilon$ is any positive constant. Define the random variable $Y_\epsilon$ by
> $$
> Y_\epsilon = 1 \text{ if } |X| \ge \epsilon
> $$
> $$
>   \text{}\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }         = 0 \text{ if } |X| \lt \epsilon
> $$
> Thus
> $$
> \mathbb E[Y_\epsilon] = 1 \cdot P(|X| \ge \epsilon) + 0 \cdot P(|X| \lt \epsilon) = P(|X| \ge \epsilon)
> $$
>
> and it **certainly must be true that** $X^2 \ge X^2Y_\epsilon \ge \epsilon^2 Y_\epsilon$
>
> From this it also follows that
> $$
> \mathbb E[X^2] \ge \mathbb E[\epsilon^2 Y_\epsilon] = \epsilon^2 \mathbb E[Y_\epsilon] = \epsilon^2 P(|X| \ge \epsilon)
> $$
> and thus
> $$
> P(|X| \ge \epsilon) \le \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \mathbb E[X^2]
> $$
> Which gives the Chebyshev inequality.

I'm struggling to understand how he goes from
$$X^2 \ge X^2Y_\epsilon$$

to the inequality

$$ X^2Y_\epsilon \ge \epsilon^2 Y_\epsilon$$

It doesn't seem obvious to me.

Comment: One approach: Consider the two cases: (i) check that it's true when $|X|\geq\epsilon$ and (ii) check that it's true when $|X|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

If $X^2 Y_\epsilon \geq \epsilon^2 Y_\epsilon$, then $X^2$ must be larger then $\epsilon^2$...

...if  $Y_\epsilon \neq 0$. And the latter is only the case when $|X| > \epsilon$.